# Creating vector logos for embedding in other tex documents

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm interested in drawing a logo with Tikz to embed either as a PDF or as a code snippet in other Tex documents. In order to do this, I'd like to draw the logo in a small PDF file, size 1 inch by 1 inch. I try the following code and curiously, it seems that geometry has additional parameters influencing the shape of the PDF. What must I "set to zero" so that drawing a 1inch diameter circle intersects all edges of the PDF as viewed?

```
\documentclass{slides}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1in, paperheight=1in, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.5, 0.5) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
```

Then you don't even need the `geometry` package. It automatically sets the size of the 'canvas' to the size of the bounding box.

---

*Edit by percusse:* Still, for the fun of it, you can get rid of the `\hoffset` and also you should make sure that the `line width` is also taken into account. Lastly, you need to use `in` instead of the default `cm` for the units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1in, paperheight=1in, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\hoffset{0in}
\begin{document}
\noindent\tikz\draw (0.5in+0.5pt,0.5in) circle (0.5in-0.25pt);
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added a simple example. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't aware of the "standalone" doc class which was clearly what I should've been using. Interesting example with the use of hoffset and noindent additionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a tight vector image by using `preview` package as follow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt% you can set it to 0pt if you don't need a border.
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1in}% one unit equals to 1 inch.
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](1,1)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](0.5,0.5){0.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```